# Ada Constraint_error invalid enumeration value

Tags: ada

Im so close to finishing this lab I can taste it. I realize my Ada code is very novice as I just began working with it this semester. The error seems to persist at location 19 when I try to use 'put' on mainStk at said location. Im wondering why i cannot get access to mainStk(19) as this is what seems to be the issue.

This is the error code

```
    raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : mainStk.Input_IO.Put: invalid enumeration value [2018-03-07 18:46:16] process exited with status 1, elapsed time: 05.40s
```

This is the .adb its appearing in.

```
        with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;

package body ProcsAndFuncs is

   Base: array(1..N+1) of integer;         --self descriptive arrays to maintain stacks
   Top: array(1..N) of integer;                 
   Old_Top: array(1..N) of integer;                            
   mainStk: array(LowerB..UpperB) of Input;    
   package Int_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(Integer);
   use Int_IO;                                           --IO routine for my integers
   package Input_IO is new Ada.TExt_IO.Enumeration_IO(Input);
   use Input_IO;                                         --IO routine for Data

   procedure ReA_Move(Snum: integer; Data: Input) is  --procedure follows ReA1-ReA6 in notes (pg 22-23)

      New_Base : array (1..N+1) of integer;     --following variables from notes being declared and initalized
      Growth : array (1..N) of Integer;
      Alpha, Beta, Sig, Tau: float:= 0.00;
      Growth_All: float:= 0.87;             --divide 87% avail memory based on growth
      Equal_All: float:= 0.13;               --divide 13% avail memory equally
      TotalInc, Avail, Delt: integer:= 0;
      min_space: Integer:= 1;
      J: integer;

   begin
      Avail:= M-L0;      --beginning ReA1 from notes (p.22)
      J:= N;
      new_line;
      Put("Contents of Old Top(J), Top(J), and Base(J) before repacking as requested:");
      new_line;
      for i in 1..N loop
         put("old top(");  put(i,1);  put(")= ");
         put(old_top(i),1);
         put(".. Top(");  put(i,1);  put(")= ");
         put(top(i),1);       
         put(".. Base(");  put(i,1);  put(")= ");
         put(base(i),1);
         new_line;    
      end loop;
      while J>0 loop                                   --ReA1 from notes
         Avail:= Avail-(Top(j)-Base(j));
         if top(j) > old_top(j) then
            Growth(j):= Top(j)-old_top(j);
            TotalInc:= TotalInc+Growth(j);
         else
            growth(j) := 0;
         end if;
         J:= J-1;
      end loop;

      if Avail < (Min_Space - 1) then                        --ReA2 from notes
         Put("Insufficient memory for re-packing to occur, terminating.");
         raise Program_Error;
      end if;

      growth_All:= 1.0-Equal_All;                           --ReA3 from notes
      Alpha:= (Equal_All * Float(Avail)) / float(N); 

      beta:= (Growth_All * Float(Avail)) / float(totalinc);      --ReA4 from notes

      new_base(1):= base(1);                                   --ReA5 from notes
      Sig:= 0.0;
      for j in 2..N loop
         tau:= sig+alpha+(float(Growth(j-1)) * Beta);
         new_base(j):=new_base(j-1)+(top(j-1)-base(j-1))+Integer(float'Floor(tau))-Integer(float'Floor(sig));
         sig:= tau;
      end loop;

      Top(Snum):= Top(Snum)-1;                         --ReA6

      for j in 2..N loop                               --MoA1 from notes
         if new_base(j) < base(j) then
            delt:= base(j)-new_base(j);
            for l in integer range(base(j) + 2)..(top(j)) loop
               mainStk(l-delt):= mainStk(l);
            end loop;
            base(j):= new_base(j);
            top(j):= top(j)-delt;
         end if;
      end loop;

      for j in 2 .. N loop                           --MoA2 from notes
         if new_base(j) > Base(j) then
            delt:= new_base(j)-base(j);
            for l in (Top(j)-1)..(base(j)+1) loop    
               mainStk(l+delt):= mainStk(l);
            end loop;
            base(j):= new_base(j);
            top(j):= top(j)+delt;
         end if;
      end loop;

      top(Snum):= Top(Snum)+1;                  --jumping back to ReA6
      mainStk(Top(Snum)):= data;
      new_line;
      Put("Bases and tops after repack as requested:"); new_line;
      for J in 1..N loop                                            --prepare for potential overflow
         Put("Base("); put(j,1); put(")= "); 
         put(base(j),1);
         Put(", Top("); put(j,1); put(")= "); 
         put(top(j),1);
         new_line;
         old_top(J):= Top(J);
      end loop;
      new_line;
      put("continuing tansactions..");
   end ReA_move;   

   procedure output is            --declaration for procedure 'output' (procedures return no value)
   begin
      new_line;
      new_line;
      for i in 1..N loop          --outputs conents of each transaction as requested
         put("Stack #:");
         put(i); new_line;
         for j in base(i)+1..top(i) loop
            if j < base(i+1) then
               put("   Loc[" & integer'image(j) & " ]: ");
               put(mainStk(j));          --put problem?
               new_line;
            end if;
         end loop;
      end loop;
   end output;   

   procedure Push(Stack:Integer; Data:Input) is --procedure since no value returned
   begin
      top(Stack):= top(Stack)+1;                  --Insertion into stack from notes
      if Top(Stack) > Base(Stack+1) then
         new_line;
         put("Overflow occured, calling Reallocate");  new_line;         --report overflow
         ReA_move(stack, data);                                --determine if additional space can be made
      else
         mainStk(Top(Stack)):= data;                  --insert data into stack
         output;
      end if;
   end Push;

   function Pop(Stack: Integer) return Input is    --function used to return value
      data: Input;
   begin
      if top(stack) = base(stack) then              --implement Pop as in deletion from stack pg 21
         put("Reporting underflow..");
         return empty;
      else
         data:= mainStk(top(stack));
         top(stack):= top(stack)-1;
         return (mainStk(top(Stack)));
      end if;
   end Pop;

begin
      Put("Initial Tops and Bases:    ");
      for j in 1..N loop                  --loop equally initializes Tops & Bases prior to transactions
         base(j):= Integer(Float'Floor(((Float(j) - 1.0) / Float(N) * Float(M - L0)) + Float(L0)));
         Top(j):= Base(j);
         old_top(j):= top(j);
         new_line;
         Put("Base(");
         put(j,1);
         put(") = ");
         put("Top(");
         put(j,1);
         put(")= ");
         put(top(j),1);
   end loop;
   new_line;
   put("Base(5)= 27");
end;
```

This is my generic which may or may not be needed.

```
 generic
   N:integer;
   M:integer;
   L0:integer;
   LowerB:integer;
   UpperB:integer;

package ProcsAndFuncs is

   type Input is (Zhou, Wei, Burris, Shashidhar, Deering, An, Lester, Yang, Smith, Arcos, 
                  Rabieh, Song, Cho, Varol, Karabiyik, Cooper, McGuire, Najar, Hope, Pray, NoHope, empty); 
   procedure ReA_move(Snum : in integer; Data : Input);
   procedure push(stack : integer; Data : Input);
   function pop(stack : Integer) return Input;
   procedure output;
end;
```

Comment: Perhaps not a problem at this location, but i always get a problem after calling reallocate and returning to input.

Comment: `mainStk` isn’t initialized, so you’ll probably get an invalid enumeration value if you attempt to `put` from an element that you haven’t yet written to. Given your timescales I suppose you’ll have to bull through it, but I’d have at least separated the "stack" logic into another package (perhaps using `Ada.Containers.Vectors` under the hood, which would remove the need for `ReA_Move`. Why is this visible to your package users?)

Comment: Compiling with `-gnatwa` (all standard warnings) tells me that `pop` should return `data` (i.e. the value that was on the stack until you popped it)

Comment: Compiling to get stack trace on exception will help pin down the failure... something like `gnatmake my_app.adb -g -bargs -E -largs -no-pie` where -g includes debug info, -E (binder args) adds stack trace generation code, and -no-pie (linker args) turns address space randomisation off, allowing the stack trace to be dumped with `readline` to get source code file/line number info.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example, which shows the same behaviour?  And please include enough source text to allow us to replicate the behaviour you observe.

Comment: You can’t expect us to work out what your driver program would need to say to generate the behaviour you report, so unless you can provide one you’re unlikely to get any more answers.